# Crear servidor propio de Git

Tags: apache2, gitlab, centos7

Tengo un servidor centOS 7, en el que tengo instado gitlab, al que necesito cambiar el puerto 80 por el 8080. Para poder tener apache corriendo en el puerto 80.

Entro en el archivo de configuración de gitlab gitlab.rb agregando lo siguiente:

```
external_url "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080"

nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = { "X-Forward-Port" => "8080", "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" => "<xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>:8080" }

gitlab-ctl reconfigure

gitlab-ctl restart
```

Cuando intento entrar a Gitlab con la dirección http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 se muestra una página en blanco con el logo de gitlab y el texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de que se me puede estar pasado por alto?, tengo que cambiar el puerto en alguna otra parte para que Gitlab cargue correctamente.

Comment: Revisaste los requerimientos de hardware de gitlab? El error 502 se genera porque el servidor se demora mucho en responder, por lo general porque no tiene suficientes recursos de memoria

Comment: El servidor tiene 8Gb de RAM la cantidad mínima recomendada es de 4Gb para 100 usuarios. El servidor no arroja ningún tipo de alerta que me haga pensar que se está quedando sin RAM. Si hago correr a Gitlab por el puerto 80 este arranca y funciona de manera correcta.

Comment: Solucionado el problema se encontraba en que Gitlab usa el puerto 8080 para servicios internos. Cambiando el puerto en  gitlab.rb  todo ha vuelto ha funciona de nuevo. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solucionado el problema se encontraba en que Gitlab usa el puerto 8080 para servicios internos. Cambiando de puerto en gitlab.rb todo ha vuelto ha funciona de la manera esperada. :) :)